# Storing results from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run a SQL query to gather data and write to a array. I want to be able to use this array to later run some if statements to see if the data that was retrieved meets certain requirements needed. I am very novice to C# and if there is a better way of doing this please point me in the right direction. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static class DBconnect
    { 

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static void sqlConnect()

        {
            var qSql = "Select con.FIRSTNAME, Con.LASTNAME, Con.EMAIL, Act.USERFIELD1 'SerialNumber', ACT.ACCOUNT, TTC.SOFTWAREMAINTENANCE, TTC.HARDWAREMAINTENANCE " +
                    "from CONTACT CON Inner join ACCOUNT ACT on ACT.ACCOUNTID = CON.ACCOUNTID " +
                    "Inner join TTCONTRACTS TTC on TTC.ACCOUNTID = ACT.ACCOUNTID " +
                    "Where Con.EMAIL is not null and Act.USERFIELD1 is not null and " +
                    "ISNUMERIC(Act.USERFIELD1) = 1 and con.EMAIL like '%@%'";

            //Creates connection to sql database
            string connectionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-MO813OQ\SalesLogic; Initial Catalog=SalesLogix_Pull; Integrated Security = True";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            //Sql command to run the query's
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(qSql, cnn);

            QueryResults[] allRecords = null;

            using (query)
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (var reader = query.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var list = new List<QueryResults>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                        list.Add(new QueryResults
                        {
                            FIRSTNAME = reader.GetString(0),
                            LASTNAME = reader.GetString(1),
                            EMAIL = reader.GetString(2),
                            SERIALNUMBER = reader.GetInt32(3),
                            ACCOUNT = reader.GetString(4),
                            USERFIELD1 = reader.GetInt32(5),
                            SOFTWAREMAINTENANCE = reader.GetBoolean(6),
                            HARDWAREMAINTENANCE = reader.GetBoolean(7)
                        });
                    allRecords = list.ToArray();
                }

                try
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error has occured.");
                }
            }


        }


    }
```

and

```
class QueryResults
    {
        public string  FIRSTNAME { get; set; }

        public string LASTNAME { get; set; }

        public string EMAIL { get; set; }

        public int USERFIELD1 {get; set;}

        public int SERIALNUMBER { get; set; }

        public string ACCOUNT { get; set; }

        public bool SOFTWAREMAINTENANCE { get; set; }

        public bool HARDWAREMAINTENANCE { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run this I usually get these Errors:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll on this part of the code:

```
list.Add(new QueryResults
                        {
                            FIRSTNAME = reader.GetString(0),
                            LASTNAME = reader.GetString(1),
                            EMAIL = reader.GetString(2),
                            SERIALNUMBER = reader.GetInt32(3),
                            ACCOUNT = reader.GetString(4),
                            USERFIELD1 = reader.GetInt32(5),
                            SOFTWAREMAINTENANCE = reader.GetBoolean(6),
                            HARDWAREMAINTENANCE = reader.GetBoolean(7)
                        });
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a job for an ORM.  I like EF 6 or EF Core, but there are many many many ORMs available out there.

Comment: Are any of the boolean or numeric columns nullable? If so, you will run into problems trying to cast DbNull.Value to those types.

Comment: What are the column types? Error is because you are trying to get the wrong type of data for a column

Comment: What about storing in [DataTable](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwia56q594DOAhWLD5AKHXLrCcgQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fpt-br%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.datatable(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEN2H6OyDEs3sWsHgxn4lG7VmV_fA&sig2=djqCmx5hH8mw_zBL-GKfsA) instead of array? DataTable exists for that purpose too, they store data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that some of your data column not return your expected output such as null value.

Try this

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
   return reader.GetString(colIndex); 
else 
   return string.Empty;
```

If that not work, You can try debug which column has issue and provide me more information.

Hope this help.

Comment: I gave this a try but it is giving me an error on the returns it says "Since "DBconnect.sqlConnect()" returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I do not quite understand what it is asking.

Answer (score 1):

For at least one of these the data type you're reading from the `SqlDataReader` doesn't match the method you're using to read it. In other words, maybe you're using `.GetInt32` to read a `varchar` value.

The easiest thing is to look at the source tables and eyeball the columns to make sure that each column you're selecting from contains the expected type. If it doesn't, see if you can cast it in your query. `USERFIELD1` looks suspicious because you're checking to see if it's numeric, which means it's not an `int`. In your query you could change

```
Act.USERFIELD1 'SerialNumber'
```

to

```
convert(int, Act.USERFIELD1) 'SerialNumber'
```

Comment: You are correct USERFIELD1 is a char not a int, when I make the change you suggest it stops the query from running at all. Thank you for the feedback though!

Answer (score 1):

I dislike hard coding indexes with the reader, in case I screw up a count, or the select changes

try this format for all of your collection initializer lines

```
SERIALNUMBER = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOridinal("SerialNumber"))
```

instead of

```
SERIALNUMBER = reader.GetInt32(3)
```

If that doesn't help, I would double check the actual column definitions in the database and make sure they are of the types you expect

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly says "Invalid Cast Exception". The format/datatype of the data stored in database and the casting in C# is miss matching. Please compare all the database column type with your C# Property type.

Comment: I looked through all of them and there were some that were wrong. They are either char or varchar. I changed them all to be strings now and I am still getting the same error.